# Google compute engine api: create global address

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a global external IP using google compute engine api, here is my code

```
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1', cache_discovery=False)
response = compute.globalAddresses().insert(project='xxx').execute()
print(response.text)
result = json.loads(response.text)
return result
```

I'm getting following error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myadcloud/global/addresses?alt=json returned "Required field 'resource' not specified">
```

cannot find any good documentation about this, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error "Required field 'resource' not specified" seems to indicated a missing resource value on API request.

Ensure review you are including the path parameters and request [body fields](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/insert?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22849876797374%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22us-central1%22%2C%22requestId%22%3A%22551b930e-54e4-11ea-a2e3-2e728ce88125%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22exteral-api-address2%22%2C%22addressType%22%3A%22EXTERNAL%22%2C%22kind%22%3A%22compute%23address%22%7D%7D#body.request_body.FIELDS-table) needed to generate your Global Address request.

Take a look into documentation examples for various code languages on the [Method: addresses.insert documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/insert?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22849876797374%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22us-central1%22%2C%22requestId%22%3A%22551b930e-54e4-11ea-a2e3-2e728ce88125%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22exteral-api-address2%22%2C%22addressType%22%3A%22EXTERNAL%22%2C%22kind%22%3A%22compute%23address%22%7D%7D#examples_1)